# Can't generate apk project that make with react native in android studio

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I have made a project with react native. now I want to generate an apk. but there isn't any generated icon as below picture and also there isn't exist Gradle script at the root of my project.

[image]

I think the Gradle script does not in the root project, is this the problem with Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Open android folder in android studio, you will see Gradle, libraries and can build apk, also if you want to generate a release apk you can do it with this command in android folder directory `./gradlew assembleRelease` or `gradlew assembleRelease`

Answer (score 0):

Run `npx react-native run-android --variant=release` from the android folder.
You can find the apk in:

```
'project_name'/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release
```